# Study continuity of the function $f(x) = \lim_{t\to+\infty} (1+x)\tan(xt)$ and sketch its graph.

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, continuity

> Given a function:
>   $$
> f(x)= \lim_{t\to+\infty} (1+x)\tan(xt)
> $$
>   Study its continuity and sketch a graph.

---

This problem comes along with several similar ones, one of which was to study the properties of the function:
$$
g(x) = \lim_{t\to+\infty}\frac{\ln(1+e^{xt})}{\ln(1+e^t)}
$$

After some algebraic manipulations, one can conclude that the function is $g(x) = 0$ for $x \le 0$ and $g(x) = x$ for $x > 0$:
$$
\lim_{t\to+\infty}\frac{\ln(1+e^{xt})}{\ln(1+e^t)} \stackrel{x > 0}{=} \\
\lim_{t\to+\infty}\frac{\ln(e^{xt})+\ln\left(1+{1\over e^{xt}}\right)}{\ln(e^t)+\ln\left(1+{1\over e^t}\right)} \sim \frac{xt}{t} = x
$$
For $x \le 0$:
$$
\lim_{t\to+\infty}\frac{\ln(1+e^{xt})}{\ln(1+e^t)} \stackrel{x \le 0}{=}\\
\lim_{t\to+\infty}\frac{\ln\left(1+{1\over e^{|x|t}}\right)}{\ln(1+e^t)} = 0
$$

A similar approach has worked for several problems of a similar kind, but the one in the question section is trickier.

---

Obviously for $x = 0$:
$$
\lim_{t\to+\infty}(1+x)\tan(xt) = 0
$$

But for other values of $x$ I couldn't study its behavior because of $\tan tx$ doesn't even have a limit for $x\ne \pi n$ and $t\to +\infty$. I've referred to [desmos](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/mwczapka29) in order to get more insights on it, but it became even more convoluted.

The question is how to study the continuity of the given function? And what its graph looks like?

Comment: The limit doesn't exist except when $x = 0$ so the problem does not make sense as stated.

Comment: @Zarrax However the keys section suggests that $f(x)$ is defined on $\Bbb R$, continuous on $(-\infty, 0)\cup(0, +\infty)$, and $x = 0$ is the point of discontinuity. So I'm confused.

Comment: @Zarrax oh god, my version of the book has a typo. I've just checked the older edition. The function there is $f(x) = (1+x)\tanh(tx)$. Not the $\tan(tx)$

Comment: @Zarrax The limit also exists at $x=-1$.

Comment: Jose Carlos Santos is right, there's $x = -1$ too, but clearly the old version of the problem is what they had in mind.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that $f$ is the null map from $\{-1,0\}$ into $\mathbb R$. And so $f$ is continuous.

Comment: Thank you for the answer, I've just found out my edition of the book has a typo. The older one has $f(x) = \lim_{t\to+\infty}(1+x)\tanh(tx)$. A [hyperbolic tangent](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/ixxn9jzxyw) is being used there.

Comment: As far as OP is concerned, this answer is correct. Thank you!

Comment: @roman But then$$\lim_{t\to\infty}(x+1)\tanh(tx)=\begin{cases}-x-1&\text{ if }x<0\\0&\text{ if }x=0\\x+1&\text{ if }x>0,\end{cases}$$which is discontinuous at $0$ and only there.